# How to use sed to replace string with backtick

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How to I can use, shell/bash script's 'sed', to replace string with content of variable and surround it by acute/backslash.

For example:

file (file.txt) containing line

```
FILE_PATH="this/is/the/file/path"
```

to be replaced like

```
FILE_PATH=`get/file/path/get.sh FILE_NAM`
```

I tried the following sed, but did not work for me

```
SCRIPT_PATH="get/file/path/get.sh FILE_NAM"
sed -i "s,\"this/is/the/file/path\",`$SCRIPT_PATH`,g" $file
```

above resulted

```
FILE_PATH=get/file/path/
```

but expected is

```
FILE_PATH=`get/file/path/get.sh FILE_NAM`
```

Can someone please help me to get replace string with content of a variable with acure around value of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the issue is purely with `sed`, your command isn't formatted quite correctly. It looks like the overall issue is you aren't printing the escape sequence for the ` character, which is a special character in bash for executing shell commands within another command.

Based on your desired results and sample code, the following works for me in bash.

```
SCRIPT_PATH="this/is/the/file/path"
sed -i "s|\"this/is/the/file/path\"|\`$SCRIPT_PATH\`|g" file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer as below:

```
SCRIPT_PATH="get/file/path/get.sh FILE_NAM"
sed -i "s,\"this/is/the/file/path\","\`"$SCRIPT_PATH"\`",g" $file
```